# PowerShell Forms, Try/Catch Not Stopping Application Properly

Tags: powershell, error-handling, try-catch

#### Problem

I am working with PowerShell to create an application that uses a GUI created using Forms. While trying to maintain a modular programming style, I have more or less slammed into a wall that I cannot seem to find a way around, and was hoping the community could help.

In my application, I am trying to create custom error catching utilizing try/catch statements, but have found that when I call upon a factory function and that function has an error, the application will display said error as intended, but will continue to process as if it was successful...

I have even tried using `exit` and `break`, but end up with an "Unhandled Exception" error that immediately follows my custom error. I have even set `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` but still get this problem.

Here is a simplified sample of my code so that you can see what is happening:

```
Button_Click = {
    ValidatePathing -BackupPath $BackupPath.Text
    If (!(Test-Path $BackupPath.Text)) {
        # Attempt to Create it
    }

    # bunch of code
}

Function ValidatePathing ([string]$BackupPath){
    Try {
        If (!$BackupPath) {
            throw "customError1"
        }

        If ($BackupPath -match "\|") {
            throw "customError2"
        }
    }
    Catch {
        If ($_.Exception.Message -eq "customError1") {
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("some message")
        }
        ElseIf ($_.Exception.Message -eq "customError2") {
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("some message")
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when the code hits a section like `ValidatePathing` and a custom error happens, the error message will display as expected, but the code will then step over/through the section and continues to process the rest of the code, despite the error.

#### Question

Does anyone know PowerShell well enough to explain how to properly handle a situation like this so that the code stops running after hitting a nested error like this?

Comment: I would suggest using `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()` instead of the `throw` keyword.  It takes an `ErrorRecord` as a constructor.

Comment: Additionally, in your code, you're not doing anything with your catch statement except displaying a message, so you'd need to terminate the process in some way (`Stop-Process -Id $global:PID`)

Comment: Ah I see. That did exactly what I wanted. Thank you once again

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 The `Stop-Process`, will that also terminate the Form and action, or simply terminate the action?

Comment: The `Stop-Process` bit will kill whatever the function is being called from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure your `Try` is being handed a terminating error as it's designed to handle, utilize `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()`.  This can take an `ErrorRecord` object as a constructor, allowing you to catch specific exception types.